# match text up until some characters not including them

Tags: regex

This is an example text:

```
E) RWY 09R/27L DUE 
RUNWAY 
ALERT FGF
F)xxx
G)xxx
```

I need to match a text after line E) up until line F) not including it.
But the problem is that sometimes line F) can be absent, then i need to match until G). Furthermore none of those might present.
So far I tried such regex:

```
E\)\s*([^(?:F\)|G\))]*).*
```

And I thought it worked but if I have G or F letter in my text of line E) then it cuts it there. What can be the solution?

Comment: Try this regex:`[A-Z]+\)[\s\S]+?(?=\s*(?:[A-Z]+\)|$))` and the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pH4HM8/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PCRE (and it seems you do), you can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookahead) assertion to constrain the matching of `.*`:

```
(?s)E\)\s*(.*(?=F\))|.*(?=G\)))
```

After we activate the `DOTALL` mode with `(?s)` (you can alternatively use the `s` modifier), and the dot `.` now matches (also) the newline, this will capture into the first group `\1` either the complete text after `E)` and before `F)`, or the complete text after `E)` and before `G)`. See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/XNvOq8/2).

If you also want to handle the case when neither `F)` nor `G)` are present, you can add the third case with `$` as anchor (zero-width end of string assertion):

```
(?s)E\)\s*(.*(?=F\))|.*(?=G\))|.*$)
```

Your original regex does not work because the range `[^F)|G)]` will match the first occurrence of *any character* not specified in the range (for example `a`). Almost all metacharacters (like `|`) lose their special meaning when used inside `[..]` (only `^` and `-` are handled differently).

A simpler alternative (without the lookaheads) is:

```
(?s)E\)\s*(.*F\)|.*G\))
```

but that includes the ending `F)` or `G)` in the capture group `\1`.

Comment: This works, but in case I don't have neither F) nor G) line it doesn't match my E) line text. What is missing?

Comment: ok i added : (?s)E\)\s*(.*(?=F\))|.*(?=G\))|.*) and seems ok so far

Comment: If you want to match until the end, in case neither F or G are present, you can use `$` as anchor: `(?s)E\)\s*(.*(?=F\))|.*(?=G\))|.*$)` (see my edit), but the greedy `.*` you added should work too.